# CoreText Warnings When Using wxPython

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, osx-mavericks, core-text

When using wx with Matplotlib in a Python program on OS X Mavericks, I'm getting the following warnings:

```
2014-05-20 23:42:06.107 Python[1750:d07] CoreText performance note: Client called CTFontCreateWithName() using name ".Lucida Grande UI" and got font with PostScript name ".LucidaGrandeUI". For best performance, only use PostScript names when calling this API.
```

It seems to be an error in the underlying C++ code, and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wx-users/XrW3kLsbS3Y) seems to indicate that the issue has been fixed, but I have no idea how to go about fixing the issue for myself. Will I have to get the source and build it myself? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Otherwise, a way to simply suppress these warning would be good enough, they aren't causing any ill effects.

Comment: I have this same problem.  Any luck getting rid of these messages, or figuring it out?

Comment: This warning goes away when I run my code using Enthought Canopy, instead of simply running it in the terminal.  It's odd because I'm using the Enthought Canopy Python distribution either way.  I'm not sure what this means.